# раскрасить View разными цветами по горизонтали

Tags: java, android, view, диаграммы

Как нарисовать View у которого фон окрашен в разные цвета?

Результат должен получиться таким

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Разные цвета нарисовал так:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 80, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));
    canvas.drawLine(0,0,150,0, paint);
    paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    canvas.drawLine(150,0,350,0, paint);
    paint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
    canvas.drawLine(350,0,400,0, paint);
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    canvas.drawLine(400,0,410,0, paint);
}
```

А вот как нарисовать снизу временной интервал?

Comment: наследуете `View`, переписываете метод `onDraw()`, и там рисуете, что душе угодно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смог нарисовать вот так:

```
public class HorizontaltView extends View {

    private Paint paint;
    private Paint textPaint;

    public HorizontaltView (Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public HorizontaltView (Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        super(context, attributeSet);

        textPaint = new Paint();
        textPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        textPaint.setStrokeWidth(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 10, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));

        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 80, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawLine(0,0,150,0, paint);
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        canvas.drawLine(150,0,350,0, paint);
        paint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        canvas.drawLine(350,0,400,0, paint);
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        canvas.drawLine(400,0,410,0, paint);
        canvas.drawText("10:00", 40, 40, textPaint);
        canvas.drawText("12:00", 80, 40, textPaint);
        canvas.drawText("13:00", 160, 40, textPaint);
    }
}
```